# Best practice for ASP.NET restful webservice to inform client about more data

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest

I have a WCF RESTful web service which returns list of objects to the client. Size of each object is roughly 10K. As the default response size (**System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportBindingElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize**) is 64K, the service cannot send more than 6 objects at a time. Assume there are 60 objects, what is the best way for the client to receive all 60 objects. Is there anyway in WCF to inform to the client that there is more data to read from server? Please note that changing default MaxReceivedMessageSize parameter value is not an option.

Any help is highly appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a link header as a HTTP header with rel="next" that has a URI that points to the next set of objects.  See [RFC 5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988) for syntax of link headers.